# DIV not taking parent height 3 columns

Tags: html, css

```
<div class='main_container' style='overflow:hidden; height:100%; height: auto !important; min-height:100%; width:100%;'>
    <div class='float_left' style='width:100px; height:100%;'>
    </div>
    <div class='float_right' style='width:100px;'>
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
    <div class='content'>
         //elastic content that sometimes makes the page longer or shorter
    </div>
</div>
```

No matter how many tutorials or examples I looked at, nothing is helping me. I've tried many different combinations. As soon as I set main_container to a px height, the sidebars then, correctly, take up 100% of the height. But I can't set a px height for the main container.

---

EDIT:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHAHW.png)

The content box will not have a static height. So far what happens is that main_container adjusts it's height based on the content box, but the two sidebars don't adjust there height based on the main_containers height.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly. The divs will automatically resize based on what is inside them.

Comment: didn't i see this exact question yesterday ? Can you provide a wireframe image of what you want to display ?

Comment: Milche, I updated the OP with a wireframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses CSS tables cells that allow the left/right sidebars to take on the height of the central `.content` panel.

The HTML:

```html
<div class='main_container'>
    <div class='left_bar'></div>
    <div class='content'>
        <p>Elastic content that sometimes makes the page longer or shorter</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class='right_bar'></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
.main_container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.left_bar {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.right_bar {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.content {
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/zahPD/

As suggested in other comments, you can specify `height: 100%` or `height: inherit` to `.main_container` as required in your application.

**Reference** for `table-cell`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

**Backwards Compatibility**
Works with IE8 and above.

Comment: I think that the final touch would be to add `height: 100%` to the `.main_container`, since that seemed to be the desired result.

Comment: This worked. Though, i've always heard that tables are the wrong way to do things? Thanks anyways though, i've been working all morning on this..

Comment: Is there a way to float the bars?

Comment: You can have a solution based on floats as shown by @adrenalin - both approaches have merit and the choice may depend on the type of content you have for the sidebars and how you want the design to respond as the page width gets narrower.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Adrenalins solution did not work as well. As soon as I add float:left to the sidebar, the height of the sidebar is only as high as it's content, but not as high as main_container.

Comment: If you float the sidebars in my solution, it will break.  Why do you need to float the sidebars?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Adrift's answer, you are also overriding the `height: 100%` with the following `height: auto !important` - the latter overrides the height setting, even though it is not the source of the problem.

[Here is a Gist](https://gist.github.com/adrenalin/6116351) that works on Chrome and most likely also on other modern browsers as well.

Comment: Downvoted for suggesting `!important` since I consider it a bad coding practice

Comment: Did you read properly what I said? I did not suggest to use it, but pointed out that HE was using it.

Answer (score 0):

Div not supports height in percent using xhtml document. You use a trick like this:

```css
.main_container{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;bottom:0;
    right:0;left:0;
}
```

I've write an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vF6fY/ take a look to it

Comment: It made my main_container and all the contents within it disapear